# Lookup of dependent names in C++ template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, argument-dependent-lookup

When I try to compile this code

```
// void foobar(int); 

template <class T>
struct Foo {
  void bar(T t) { foobar(t); };
};

void foobar(int);

template class Foo<int>;
```

with g++ 4.8.2 I get the following error message

```
foo.cc: In instantiation of ‘void Foo<T>::bar(T) [with T = int]’:
foo.cc:10:16:   required from here
foo.cc:5:27: error: ‘foobar’ was not declared in this scope, and no 
             declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at 
               the point of instantiation [-fpermissive]
   void bar(T t) { foobar(t); };
                           ^
foo.cc:8:6: note: ‘void foobar(int)’ declared here, later in the translation unit
 void foobar(int);
      ^
```

(With clang 3.4 it's nearly the same).

First, I think the code is correct and *should* compile, since foobar is a dependent name in the template declaration and should be looked up only in phase two when the template is instantiated. When this is done in the last line, 'foobar(int)' is already declared. The code compiles, BTW, when I uncomment the topmost line, but both declarations are before the instantiation and so this should not matter.

Second, the error message itself seems contradictory to me. It says "no declarations were found at the point of instatiation" which is foo.cc:10:16, and it says it's declared "later" at foo.cc:8:6. For all that I know about numbers and the English language I would call that "before" not "later".

So, is it a bug in gcc or did I get something wrong? Since this seems to me a common usage pattern I can't quite believe that, however.

BTW: when I try out the second example of "Name Resolution for Dependent Types" at MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dx2zs2ee.aspx) with g++ the result is different from vc++, which (not generally, but in this specific case) would undermine this being a bug in g++.

Comment: Good question, I had another question which was the reverse of yours in a sense: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25188353/why-no-need-of-forward-declaration-in-static-dispatching-via-templates

Comment: This page does not list function calls as a valid dependent type or dependent expression: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name

Comment: @didierc Yes, you're right. Pretty strange to me that, according to that definition, an expression (t) that is of a dependent type is not a type-dependent expression. However, if I change the definition of bar to `void bar(T t) { foobar(t+static_cast<T>(1) + *(new T)); };` then I think it should fall under the categories of type-dependent expressions (doesn't it?), but the error still doesn't go away.

Comment: @didierc `foobar` is a dependent name here because it is a function being called with an argument having dependent type  (rationale: the overload resolution for the function can't be done until the type is konwn)

Comment: although the rules about dependent names were changed in C++14

Comment: @MattmcNabb thank you for your explanation, however I don't see on which point it falls in the list of that page I linked.

Comment: @didierc see [temp.dep]/1 in C++14

Comment: Ah, compound types. I misunderstood that for aggregate types (like structs,unions). Thank you all.

Comment: Found the following question on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369314/gcc-clang-and-ibm-disagree-on-how-to-perform-template-parameter-dependent-name According to the accepted answer `class A{};void foobar(A);template class Foo<A>;` should compile, and it did. Seems that the name-lookup is different because of associated namespaces that are searched for `A`, but `int` has no associated namespaces as a fundamental type. Does that make sense?

Comment: @ElmarZander yes that's fundamentally the issue

Comment: @ElmarZander: Small question: Are those neat single quotes actually from GCC or some IDE/StackOverflow auto-formatting?

Comment: @kevinarpe You mean in the error output? They come from GCC and are the unicode characters \u2018 and \u2019. clang, on the contrary, uses the normal single quote \u27. Try `echo $'\x27\u2018\u2019'` in bash to see them all together.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**tl;dr** `Foo<int>` doesn't invoke any ADL, but `Foo<X>` would (where `X` is a class type).

---

First of all, in this code `foobar` is a dependent name because of (C++14/N3936) `[temp.dep]/1`

> In an expression of the form:
>
> ```
> postfix-expression ( expression-list opt )
> ```
>
> where the postfix-expression is an unqualified-id, the unqualified-id denotes a dependent name if [...]
>
> - any of the expressions in the expression-list is a type-dependent expression (14.6.2.2), or

and `t` is a dependent name because it is part of a declaration `T t` where `T` is a template parameter and thus a dependent type.

Moving onto dependent name resolution, there is `[temp.dep.res]/1` which introduces the fact that names can be both looked up in the definition context, and the instantiation context, and defines where the instantiation context is. I have omitted that for brevity, but in this example `template class Foo<int>;` is the point of instantiation.

The next bit is `[temp.dep.candidate]/1`:

> For a function call where the *postfix-expression* is a dependent name, the candidate functions are found using the usual lookup rules (3.4.1, 3.4.2) except that:
>
> - For the part of the lookup using unqualified name lookup (3.4.1), only function declarations from the template definition context are found.
> - For the part of the lookup using associated namespaces (3.4.2), only function declarations found in either the template definition context or the template instantiation context are found.

Those last two parts are the "two phases" of two-phase lookup.   (Note - this section changed in wording from C++11 to C++14, but the effect in the same).

In the first phase, 3.4.1, no names are found for `foobar`.

---

So we move onto the second phase. The actual places that names are looked up as described in 3.4.2.  The text is long but the here are two of the relevant rules:

> - If T is a fundamental type, its associated sets of namespaces and classes are both empty.
> - If T is a class type (including unions), its associated classes are: the class itself; the class of which it is a member, if any; and its direct and indirect base classes. Its associated namespaces are the innermost enclosing namespaces of its associated classes. [...]

So when you instantiate `Foo<int>`, then the second phase of lookup does not introduce any additional namespaces to search.

However, if you change your example to have `struct X {};` and then change `int` to `X` everywhere, then the code *does* compile. This is because of the latter bullet point: ADL for an argument of class type does search the enclosing namespace of that class (which is the global namespace now), however ADL for an argument of built-in type does not search the global namespace.

Comment: ADL is invoked. ADL just doesn't consider a single namespace.

Comment: Thanks for the long answer, Matt. So according to [basic.lookup.argdep]/2 `int` has not associated namespaces and classes and so in [temp.dep.candidate]/1 and only the 'unqualified name lookup' part plays a role, which looks only at the template definition context.  Would there be any drawback, also looking into the template instatiation context as in bullet point two?

Comment: @ElmarZander If you're asking why dependent names can't be fully looked up again at the point of instantiation... I don't know, but I'm sure someone who has written a compiler could have something to say :).  Originally C++ only had phase one; then ADL was added so that things like `cout << x;` would work. Maybe they just didn't want to mess with it any more from that point.

Comment: Actually, I in gcc they did exactly that for a long time, see https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=29131. They just changed it with the release of gcc 4.7 (https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/porting_to.html) and when I look at the bug history it seems to me nobody really had an issue with that, it just wasn't quite conforming. They even describe it like that in the docs https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Name-lookup.html (which should probably be rewritten now). Anyway, I'll have to adapt my code to that, which will make it messier in some places.

Comment: This is ill-formed, period. There's no NDR or UB here. [temp.dep.candidate] says that UB occurs if "the call would be ill-formed or would find a better match had the lookup within the associated namespaces considered all the function declarations with external linkage introduced in those namespaces in all translation units, not just considering those declarations found in the template definition and template instantiation contexts." There's no associated namespaces at all.

Comment: @TC I was reading it as "if (the call would be ill-formed) or (would find a better match had the lookup within the associated namespaces...)"  , you are using a different precedence of English :)  Have edited post to go with your version now .

Comment: I think this answer is at least misleading. It starts with "In an expression of the form: `postfix-expression ( expression-list opt )`". But is the unqualified-id `foobar` even a `postfix-expression` ? It's not declared.

Answer (score 6):

Phase two lookup only includes name lookup rules that can't be applied in phase one- ADL, for example. Two-phase lookup is exactly that- some names are looked up in phase one, and some are looked up in phase two. This particular kind of name is a phase one name, as the compiler is perfectly capable of looking for `foobar` in the namespace(s) of the function during phase one.

Visual C++ does not implement two-phase name lookup.

Comment: So, is this correct behaviour from gcc 4.8.2 according to the standard?  BTW: I now also checked with gcc 4.4 and 4.6 and it compiles with both. Are they (and vc++) then not standards conforming?

Comment: One more question: how is the compiler capable of looking up foobar during phase one when the template parameters are not yet specified? (Or did I get that phase one/two thing wrong?)

Comment: @MattMcNabb I tried that, but my g++ still complains. The instantiation now comes from the line `f.bar(5)` but otherwise the errors are just the same.

Comment: @ElmarZander I mean it's correct that the compiler complains

Comment: @Puppy +1, this is the core of the issue

Comment: @ElmarZander: The compiler does not need to know the type of T to find functions in the function's own namespace. It is correct that the compiler complains.

Answer (score 1):

Looks correct to me. While overload resolution is done only in phase 2, in phase 1 you already have to know that `foobar(t)` is a function call expression. If `foobar` names a type, `t` wouldn't even be a dependent name.

Comment: Sorry, but what looks correct to you? The code or the compiler error?