# Name lookup differences between g++ and MSVS

Tags: c++, templates, base-class, name-lookup, dependent-name

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace N {
    class A {};
    void f(A a) { std::cout << "N::f\n"; }
}

void f(int i) { std::cout << "::f\n"; }

template <typename T>
class Base {
  public:
    void f(T x) { std::cout << "Base::f\n"; }
};


template <typename T>
class X : public Base<T> {
  public:
    void g() {
        T t;
        f(t);
    }
};

int main()
{
    X<N::A> x1;
    x1.g();

    X<int> x2;
    x2.g();
}
```

The code is intended to investigate how name lookup works in C++.

If I compile this program with GNU C++ (version 6.1.0), it prints:

```
N::f
::f
```

But if I compile it with Microsoft Visual Studio 2015, it prints:

```
Base::f
Base::f
```

Which is the correct behaviour, and why?

Comment: I don't know the answer to this question per say, but I do know that Microsoft Visual Studio's C++ compiler is often not standard complying.  (So my guess is that Microsoft VS is wrong)

Comment: VS 2015 should be getting really close to being standard though. Clang seems to behave like GCC after a quick check. So without knowing the details I would also assume VS is wrong. Maybe you stumbled over a bug here.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

g++ is Standard compliant here, and Visual C++ not:

> **14.6.2 Dependent names [temp.dep]**
>
> 3 In the definition of a class or class template, **the scope of a
>   dependent base class (14.6.2.1) is not examined during unqualified
>   name lookup** either at the point of definition of the class template or
>   member or during an instantiation of the class template or member.

Replacing `f()` with `this->f()` will find the base member.

Comment: Thank you, TemplateRex. I wonder why C++ has this rule. Is it because template specialization may yield a `Base` class with no `f` function?

Comment: @oz1cz exactly! There is a whole passage (9.4.2.) on this in the reference book C++ Templates the Complete Guide.

Answer (score 6):

In the function definition of the function `g` the name `f` is considered as a function declared outside the class (within the class definition this name is not declared; f is a dependent name).

```
template <typename T>
class X : public Base<T> {
  public:
    void g() {
        T t;
        f(t);
    }
};
```

So the compiler uses the ADL lookup.

However if to write an explicit call of a member function

```
class X : public Base<T> {
  public:
    void g() {
        T t;
        this->f(t);
    }
};
```

then the call of the function `f` will be considered as a call of the member function of the base class..

Thus it seems that MS VC++ 2015 has a bug.

Comment: Why is `f` considered a name declared outside the scope of the class?  Is that normal behavior and it only falls back into the class scope if nothing can be found outside the class ?

Comment: @NathanOliver It is a specific behavior of template derived classes. I have no at hand the C++ Standard so I can not get the relevant quote.

Comment: That is interesting.  I'll have to do some looking.  g++ seems to not even fall back as [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea0c1776325985e1) fails to compile.

Comment: @NathanOliver It confirms what I wrote. The name f looked outside the class definition (because in the template class definition there is no member with the name f) is not exists.

Comment: @NathanOliver  See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27178483/lookup-of-dependent-names-in-c-template-instantiation